# NiFi: MergeRecord is generating duplicates

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some troubles with the MergeRecord processor in Nifi. You can see the whole Nifi flow below: I'm getting a json array from an API, then I split it, I apply some filters and then I want to build the json array again.

[Nifi workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udzpG.png)

I'm able to build the good json array from all the chunks, but **the problem is that the processor is generating data indefinitely**. When I execute the job step by step (by starting / stopping every processors one by one) everything is fine, but when the MergeRecord is running it's generating the same data even if I stop the begin of the flow (so there is no more inputs...)

You can see a screenshot below of the data in the "merged" box that are stacking

[data stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgNzO.png)

I scheduled this processor every 10 sec, and after 30 sec you can see that it executed 3 times and generated 3 times the same file while there is no more data above. It's weird because when you look at the "original" box of the processor I can see the right original amount of data (18,43Kb). But the merged part is still increasing...

Here is the configuration of the MergeRecord:

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy7fm.png)

I suppose that I'm missing something but I don't know why !

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: You have connected `failure, original` back to MergeRecord so kind of loop there, terminate or give it to LogAttribute. Same thing is also happening with other processors as well, is there a specific requirement that you are feeding them back to the same processor?

Comment: thank you @VikramsinhShinde, it was the solution ! I put some LogAttribute after each processors to avoid this kind of behaviour.